# .format equivalent in shell script

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, shell

In `Python`, if I have a to create a string with date as suffix, we can do some thing like this:

```
date = get_todays_date()
name = "automation_results_{}'.format(date)
```

What is the equivalent of `.format` in `shell/bash` scripting language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash you can get a date string by invoking `date`:

```
name="automation_results_"$(date +%Y_%m_%d)
```

with the different options for the format string you can get any date format you prefer.

As @cdarke commented, if you have a recent version of `bash` you can also do the faster:

```
name=$(printf "automation_results_%(%Y_%m_%d)T")
```

Comment: Since the question is about string formatting, rather than use an inefficient external program (`date`), would it not have been better to show `printf -v` with the `%(%+)T`?

Comment: @cdarke if efficiency is required then using bash is the first thing that should be reevaluated. I tend to prefer using the more generic `$(...)` than having to remember that `printf` supports a special case for formatting dates, but that is certainly an option. OK if I update the answer with that als an alternative?

Comment: I agree with your sentiment about efficiency and bash in general.  In tests I timed that `printf` is about 100 times faster than the `date` program.  If you use the `printf` alternative then you should mention that it is only available from bash version 4 (many are still on 3.2).